# Is it safe to disconnect a read-only USB HD without unmounting it first?

Tags: hard-drive, file-corruption, read-only

The USB connector on my 2TB HD has been acting up after an accident and even a slight movement results in it disconnecting from my laptop.

I can't replace it right now so I was wondering if I risk data loss or data corruption when it's read-only.

Examples of read-only:

- Formatted as NTFS (Windows) but use it on Mac.
- Formatted as HFS+ (Mac) but use it on Windows.
- Pretty much any format that Android reads, but does not get to write on (not without root or 3rd party apps).

So when it's read-only can I just go ahead and use it without worrying or I should still avoid it cause it might still corrupt data?

Comment: I'd be more worried about mechanical damage caused by emergency parking, if the disk is entirely USB-powered...

Comment: @grawity Isn't such parking done simply by a magnet returning the heads to their parked position? The platters should still be creating enough air movement to keep the heads from crashing...correct?

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator How can arms which are not in physical contact with the platters (ever) crash? That’s a problem if you bang the disk into your desk while it’s reading/writing data.

Comment: @grawity Yes, that’s more realistic

Comment: @user2497 A sufficient shock can indeed cause the heads to come into contact with the surface of the platters. The only thing that keeps them from doing this during normal operation is a cushion of air created by the sheer rotational speed of the platter.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator I thought there was a vacuum in there to prevent oxidation. I guess you are right, it sounds scientific;)

Comment: Maybe it's just me but I'm not sure a definitive answer is clear, guys. Could someone explain it more simply to me? Thank you.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator You must be right, there were no seals to maintain vacuum on the disk I took apart to prove you wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do that all the time. No write actions are performed in read-only. The arms retract automagically, either by magnetic pull or some reservoir of power that engages when the disk power is pulled. You are more likely to get transfer errors from the bad connection, but fortunately a female miniUSB port costs so little you can repair that yourself. If you’ve jostled and tugged that port, it’s probably just a loose connection. Don’t waste money on a new disk, ask on EE.SE what to do.

You are probably thinking about old world disks, which would fail in mysterious ways if power was removed without a clean unmount. I haven’t had such problems since I stopped using ATA disks (for some reason). That doesn’t happen on modern disks.

Comment: So you think I should be fine? I'm not sure if it's an ATA drive though. How do I find out?

Comment: @J.Do. I know you will be fine, but tend to the loose connection on the miniUSB port. Do you want me to tell you how? (you only need three items)

Comment: @J.Do. It’s not ATA

Comment: Yes, if you can please explain more about the loose connection thing you mentioned. Also it doesn't matter if it's HFS+ on Windows or NTFS on Mac, right? Also does it make any difference if it's usb powered or externally powered? Thank you vwry much

Comment: @J.Do. I’ve had no problems with 5V or external ( 12V for 3.5”), though 12V would be preferrable to USB power. VFAT/FAT{16,32}/exFAT would be more vulnerable, since they have no journalling features, but HFS+/UFS/EXT/NTFS all do. I reiterate; I’ve never had corruption because of this issue in read-only. Happens sometimes on microSDs with some FAT version, but only if data was being written, not if it was being read.

Comment: @J.Do. You need soldering wick (2mm width), some solder with fluxcore (leaded is easiest) and a small 20W soldering iron. You could make do with one of those USB irons, though I’ve never tried them. Use the wick to desolder (more watts are better), remove the broken port, place the new port, solder it in. Put solder on your tip to make better contact. I’d like upvotes for my replies. Note: you can use a soldering gun (cheaper), but you must replace the tip with clean copper filament, 1-1.5mm diameter perhaps. Make it pointy with a pair of pliers. A soldering gun is wonderful.

Comment: @J.Do. ... all of this, except perhaps wick, can be bought in home depot or similar, or auto shops. Auto shops are more inclined to cheat on prices where I live. You need to de/solder 6 points, it’s not brain surgery. The copper wire comes on small rolls, like steel wire. It will oxidize faster exposed to air, but a roll has in excess of 10 meters wire. If you want better tool, get a TS100 with 0.8mm tip. It’s godly.

Comment: I see. I'll bookmark this and report back. Oh, by the way, is there any way to verify whether a file is corrupted or not. Like let's say for whatever reason it's not safe after all. How do we find out if there was a file corruption due to disconnecting an HD without unmounting first?

Comment: Also, how do I upvote your comments? I don't see any option to do that except for your very first one. Do I miss something?

Comment: @J.Do. You can mark the answer as accepted, and comments can be upvoted. If accessing SE via a browser, click the answer or comment. I see you have 6 pts, perhaps this makes it impossible. SE has many quirky point-based things going on... they give us peons more privilege as our points increase... at the least you should be able to answer.

Comment: @J.Do. To verify file integrity, generate a baseline. Google ‘windows batch file integrity check’ and ‘windows batch file checksum generator’. From the baseline (e.g. MD5 which is very fast (collisions are extremely rare)), you can later verify if a file has changed. For Linux/OSX, you can run `>/tmp/ext_md5.txt ; find /path/to/external_diskmount -type f -exec md5sum {} >>/tmp/ext_md5.txt \; ; gzip -9q /tmp/ext_md5.txt`. Copy /tmp/ext_md5.txt.gz to your Desktop folder, it goes away if you reboot. Best protection is to temporarily rent a VPS with >2TB storage, and save your data there. Encrypt.